# pycairo: justify text-align

Tags: python, text, alignment, cairo, justify

I use python bindings to Cairo to render text.

My question is: Is it possible to render a string using something like `text-align: justify`? Suppose I have fixed width and I want to print a paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Solved [using pangocairo]:

```
import pygtk
import cairo
import pango
import pangocairo
...
layout = pangocairo_context.create_layout()
...
layout.set_width(...)
layout.set_wrap(pango.WRAP_WORD)
layout.set_justify(True)
layout.set_text(text)
```

Comment: If you hadn't found out you should use Pango, I was going to point out that Cairo is not meant for text and is meant to be used together with Pango.

Comment: Needed `layout.set_alignment(pango.Alignment.RIGHT)`  too.